# codeigniter 404_override

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have set the $routes['404_override'] = 'city/switch_site'

now in my city controller

class City extends CI_Controller {

```
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function switch_site( ) {
        $this->load->helper('url'); // load the helper first
        $city = $this->uri->segment(1);
        $segment_cnt = 1;
        $valid_url = '';

        switch( $city ) {

            case 'pune':
                        $segments = $this->uri->segment_array(2);
                        foreach($segments as $value) {
                            if($segment_cnt > 1) {
                                $valid_url .= $this->uri->slash_segment($segment_cnt);
                            }
                            $segment_cnt++;
                        }
                        $this->config->set_item('cityid',1);
                        $this->config->set_item('cityname','pune');
                        echo APPPATH.'controllers/'.$valid_url;
                        include_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$valid_url);
                        break;
            case 'mumbai':
                        $segments = $this->uri->segment_array(2);
                        foreach($segments as $value) {
                            if($segment_cnt > 1) {
                                $valid_url .= $this->uri->slash_segment($segment_cnt);
                            }
                            $segment_cnt++;
                        }
                        $this->config->set_item('cityid',2);
                        $this->config->set_item('cityname','mumbai');
                        include_once(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$valid_url);
                        break;
            default:


        }
    }
}
```

how do i now pass the correct url to codeigniter router

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this all wrong. Inside your switch instead of including other controllers which will not work use the redirect() to take them where they should go.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i scrapped this idea and instead used codeigniter native routes and pre_system hooks to get the result i needed